# How to Convert one Vector Data to another Vector Data in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

```
Class ShootGame implements IGame
{

}

//ShootGame Vector 

 var shootGames:Vector.<ShootGame> = new Vector.<ShootGame>();
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   shootGames.push(new ShootGame());
}



var igames:Vector.<IGame> = //What is the Simplest method to convert ShootGame to IGame Vector

//I am doing like

igames = new Vector.<IGame>();

for(i=0;i < shootGames.length;i++)
{

igames.push(shootGames[i]);

}
```

Comment: some text is not visible, var igames:Vector . < IGame > = new Vector . < IGame > ();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more convenient way to do that.

```
var igames:Vector.<IGame> = Vector.<IGame>(shootGames);
```

Notice that when you use "Vector.< IGame >(shootgames)" you are not making a typecast, instead you are creating a new Vector instance and populating it with the content of the "shootGames" Vector.

For more detailed information, go [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Vector%28%29).

Sample code:

```
var shootGames:Vector.<ShootGame> = new Vector.<ShootGame>();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    shootGames.push(new ShootGame());
}

var igames:Vector.<IGame> = Vector.<IGame>(shootGames);

trace("shootGames.length", shootGames.length); //20
trace("igames.length", igames.length); //20
```

Comment: When i do var igames:Vector.<IGame> = Vector.<IGame>(shootGames); It still shows igames length to zero.

Comment: Are you sure that the shootGames Vector isn't empty? I've added a sample code to the answer; when I run it I get the same length for both Vectors.

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly used new keyword infront of Vector,which created that error.